# How to execute a function dynamically within local scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am trying to implement something similar to google analytics.

```
(function() {

   var id = '';
   function setId() { //do something};

   var overrideObj = function() {

      this.push = function() {
           if(typeof window[arguments] == 'function')
                    window[arguments]();
      }
   };
}());
```

I try to call `_tracker.push(['setId'])` from my code.

The above code fails at typeof `window[arguments] == 'function'`. If I remove the self executing function block from around this code. It works fine.

How do I check for the scope of the function and if there is function with such a name like `setId`.

Comment: Probably the page is not fully loaded? Use window.onload = function(){}

Comment: What are you trying to do, really? it's obvious that if you define a function in a closure, it won't be in global scope… and your code already checks if there is a global function with a given name, so obviously you know how to do that check

Comment: I need to invoke a function dynamically which has been defined inside the anonymous function.
(function() {

   function setId() { //do something};

   var overrideObj = function() {

      this.push = function() {
           
     arguments[0] will hold the string value 'setId'
     I need to check if setId is a function in this scope and execute it
      }
 }
})();